# How to read from SSLStream when you don't know the length?

Tags: c#, sslstream

Guys i'm trying to use SSLStream to test my app and so far it goes well (the client/server auth successfully), but the problem i have is reading:

How to know whether or not i have reached the end?

Microsoft's example with "EOF" simply does not work and i have tried "\r\n\r" comparison, but sometimes with long responses, it cuts out and thus i can only get a portion of the information. How can i read from this stream without knowing how long is the stream itself?

I've also tried comparing the last position of the stream with a variable that keeps the last position of the last loop and this does not work too (when you try to Read, but you've reached the end you get IOException).

Answer (score 0):

When there is no more data to be read from the stream, `SSLStream.Read` will return zero.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's not happening in my case. I get IOException if i don't break out of the reading loop. I really don't understand what's the problem. I authenticate to my client, the client sends data and fails to read it unless i break.

Comment: Are you in control of both ends of the connection and what IOException are you getting exactly?

Comment: Yeah, i ended up doing a really nasty way - i'm waiting for the exception to kick in, to know that there is no more content in the stream. Coupled with timeout tweaking, works kinda good, but its a really nasty way to read from the stream. I think MS have to improve SSLStream a lot more, to be used in production environment.